# How to draw a border around a custom control using the WINAPI?

Tags: winapi, mfc

I have a dialog that has no border.  In it is a control that has no border that extends to 2 pixels away from the edge of the containing dialog.  I would like to draw a border around the control on the dialog.  This can be done in the `WM_PAINT` message handler.  I can draw a border around the control, that's not the issue.

My questions are:

Is there a standard WINAPI call that will draw the border in the correct colour?  If that isn't available, is there some WINAPI that will get me the correct system colour?  I've attempted to use `DrawEdge()`, `FrameRect()`, `DrawFocusRect()`, but they all aren't quite right.

I've tagged this as MFC as well as WINAPI because MFC is what I'm using and it is built on the WINAPI.

Comment: `FrameRect()` was close, but it had a slight ghost of colour on the inner pixel of the rectangle when using a stock `GRAY_BRUSH`, so it's not quite right.

Comment: Try `FrameRect(hdc, &rc, GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DSHADOW))`, it's probably the same as `GRAY_BRUSH` on default theme, but it should be more compatible with theme settings.

Comment: If Visual Styles are enabled, you should use [`DrawThemeEdge()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773298.aspx) instead of `DrawEdge()` or `FrameRect()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Documentation for `DrawThemeEdge` comes up short. I think `DrawThemeEdge` ignores part and state id and behaves the same way as `DrawEdge`. It draws old 3-d style raised and sunken borders regardless of part and state id. `DrawThemeBackground` seems to be responsible for drawing borders as well as background for buttons etc.

Comment: The correct API to use is [`DrawThemeBackground()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773289(v=vs.85).aspx). This [blog post](http://www.patchou.com/projects/richedit/) explains it in depth. It's for RichEdit but can be applied to custom controls aswell. You'll find the actual drawing code on page 2 in the method `OnNCPaint()`.